# How to get the result from the asynctask back to my main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

This is the code in the AsyncTask class:
    package com.mermit.enter;

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

public class isOnlineTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    public static Boolean networkStatus;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        /*try {
            int timeoutMs = 1500;
            Socket sock = new Socket();
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);

            sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
            sock.close();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) { return false; }*/
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // result holds what you return from doInBackground
        networkStatus = result;
    }
}
```

This is the code that matters in my main class. The function isOnline gets called in an if statement and is expected to return the boolean from the asynctask. I want the main thread to wait till a response has been returned from the asynctask, which is why I use .get(). I looked through a lot of questions on the site but couldn't find a fix for my specific situation. Logcat doesn't give an error message or anything strange at all either, which doesn't help.

```
package com.mermit.enter;

import static com.mermit.enter.isOnlineTask.networkStatus;

...

public boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        new isOnlineTask().get();
        return networkStatus;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

edit: I also tried
`return new isOnlineTask().execute()`
instead of
`new isOnlineTask().get();
return networkStatus;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AsyncTask is used for doing background operation, so you should not try to stop the execution of the UI thread. `onPostExecute()` is invoked on the UI thread so here you can do everything you need to do after the task is completed. If you need to know in your main class whether the task is completed you can do something like this

**isOnlineTask**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    MainClass.taskIsCompleted(result)
}
```

**MainClass**

```
public class MainClass {

    private static boolean isTaskCompleted;

    public void genericMethod() {
        if(isTaskCompleted()) {
            // your operation here
        }
    }

    private boolean isTaskCompleted() {
        return isTaskCompleted;
    }

    public static void taskIsCompleted(boolean bool) {
        isTaskCompleted = bool;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to provide a listener object in the AsyncTask's constructor and invoke it on onPostExecute callback. For instance:

```
public class isOnlineTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
   private NetworkStatusListener mListener;

   public interface NetworkStatusListener{
      void isStatusAvailable(Boolean result);
   }

   // your code...
   public isOnlineTask(NetworkStatusListener listener){
      this.mListener = listener;
   }
   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // result holds what you return from doInBackground
        if (mListener != null){
            mListener.isStatusAvailable(result);
        }
    }
}
```

then on the MainClass:

```
new isOnlineTask(new NetworkStatusListener{
       void isStatusAvailable(Boolean result){
          //.. do something with the result
       }
   }
).execute();
```